# is it possible to drop and create sequence in oracle 11g

Tags: sequence

I am a newbie to sequences, I need to know that, is it possible to use if else block in sequence? To check if sequence exist drop in if block and in else block re create the same sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear to me. I am trying to reply as per my understanding.

> is it possible to use if else block in sequence?

If by above statement you are trying to know whether we can use if else construct inside the body of a sequence DDL, then the answer is - No, we cant. The sequence DDL has some predefined paramaters that we need to mentione while creating the sequence. If-else construct can be written inside a plsql block only and sequence DDL does not have provision to have any plsql block unlike trigger. Hence, if-else can not be mentioned inside a sequence.

> To check if sequence exist drop in if block and in else block re
>   create the same sequence.

From the above statement it seems you are trying to know whether we can create sequence inside a plsql block, because the flow that you have mentioned above for the if-else checking can be done inside a plsql block only. The answer to that is - Yes, a sequence can be created inside plsql block using execute immediate. Please see the code below for your case -

```
if seq_exists then
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('drop sequence seq');
else
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('create sequence seq start with 1 cache 500');
end if;
```

Comment: Yes, we can't put condition in sequence. Thanks Subhas.